# Why Rails Works Only When I'm root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, bash

I'm on Mac OSX 10.7.4. So I installed rails with RubyGem while being root.

When I'm root, `rails -v` yields this:

```
bash-3.2# rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
```

But when I'm not root, `rails -v`, yields this:

```
Sreejiths-MacBook-Pro:~ sreejith$ rails -v
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.2.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rubygems-bundler-1.1.0, rvm-1.11.3.5] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /opt/local/bin/rails:22
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

When at a terminal as root, what is the load path for the gems. You can find this out by going into irb and typing `$LOAD_PATH`. Is the `$LOAD_PATH` something you have access to? Did the gems get installed into root's home directory (or a subdirectory)?

Are you using anything like rbenv or rvm? Both of these tools set up rubies per user, not per system. So having one set of gems as root would be insufficient when you're logged on as you.

Finally, you can always try `sudo gem install bundler` to reinstall bundler, then `bundle install` to reinstall your gems.

Comment: +1 for using RVM, it really ties the room^H^H Ruby and gems together.